# How to run long SQL scripts from .net?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm writing a tool to automate some dba tasks. For example, Ola Hallengren (https://ola.hallengren.com/) has some fantastic, free maintenance solutions and Brent Ozar has an amazing First Responder kit that DBAs often install and run for virtually every client that hires them.

I want to automate this, but the problem I run into is that I want to run these scripts programmatically so that the user can do everything through my application, but they are much larger than the 8k limit `ExecuteNonQuery()` can handle for the `CommandText` of a `SqlCommand`.

At this point, my best idea is to break the scripts up into chunks under 8k and do it based on where the nearest "GO" statement is before the 8k mark and then run multiple statements this way.

Is this my best option, or is there a better way? I am happy to do this with ADO.net, SMO, or any other framework that handles this if there is one.

EDIT: So my idea won't even work because there are batches that are over 8k between GO commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the SQLCMD tool with input file parameter. You will not have limitation on the size of the file.

[Reference article on calling SQLCMD through c#](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/run-sql-server-scripts-using-c)

```cs
// Calls the sqlcmd
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("sqlcmd", @" -S .\sqlexpress -i C:\backup.sql");
//  Indicades if the Operative System shell is used, in this case it is not
info.UseShellExecute = false;
//No new window is required
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
//The windows style will be hidden
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
//The output will be read by the starndar output process
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = info;
//Start the process
proc.Start();
```

Comment: Hmm.... although this is definitely a last resort as it might require additional security. Likely the user has this security, but if at all possible I'd like to avoid needing to use the file system. Seems strange that there is just no way to run a large script programmatically :(

Comment: @BVernon, securitywise the ExecuteNonQuery using trusted connection or calling sqlcmd through trusted connection, there is no difference. But, yes, you additionally need this command line tool.

Answer (score 4):

Are you able to utilize [stored procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15)?

You could then avoid hitting any kind of character limit `ExecuteNonQuery()` may impose by simply calling the name of the procedure in the application.

Comment: Good thought, but the problem is there are many batches with lots of GO commands in between so sadly that won't work.

Comment: @bvernon you would almost certainly be able to restructure that to run in an SP.

Comment: You means a whole bunch of stored procs? Yes, I could manually break it up into tons of procs but the amount of work would be unreasonable and it's not just one script I want to do it for, and potentially others will add scripts and I don't want to have to instruct them to do that. :(